# Windows 7 graphic distortion/blur/glitch

Tags: windows-7, amd-radeon

I'm having some really strange graphic issues within windows 7, and I am utterly stumped on what's causing them or how to fix them.

A few select applications have started to contain a rather annoying graphic glitch where the contents of the window appear to blur over the span of 2 seconds. If the text is blurred, it will tend to go away as I select it, but comes back pretty soon after.

It's rather hard to put this issue into words, so I have taken some screenshots.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

The situation actually got worse after updating video card drivers, as it used to only happen in Visual Studio, and even then it was minor enough for me to still be able to work with.

My system spec is as follows:

> Legit Windows 7 Ultimate
>   Intel core i7 2600
>   Corsair CMX8GX3M2A1333C9 8GB (2x4GB) DDR3
>   XFX Radeon HD5770 1GB XXX Edition
>   ASRock H67M-GE Motherboard

I'm thinking it's a graphics card issue, and considering that I have one of the defective Intel 67 chipset motherboards, I am considering picking up a new graphics card and motherboard tomorrow. So I'm hoping to get a response fairly soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does most likely look to be a graphics issue, if you have an old GPU around, just replace it with the ATI one and see if it does the same thing, if it does then it's the motherboard, if not consider trying the GPU in another system to verify. That way you can save your time if the issue isn't with the GPU or motherboard.

Comment: Can't believe i didn't think of that myself. I plugged in an old nvidia GeForce 8800 GTS i had lying around, let windows update grab the driver for me and everything was fine again. So it looks like it was the video card. That's the last time i buy from ATI haha.

So, looks like i have to buy a new GPU and motherboard since my SATA ports are already failing from the defective chipset. Haha, wonderful.

Anyway, thanks heaps for help! Much appreciated.

Comment: Also as a note, the ATI 5000 series cards have actually been one of the most popular cards because of their price to performance ratio. I myself have had an ATI 5850 for a very long time now and it's been doing great. Don't give up too quickly on one bad card. It does happen.